# How do I cascade populate drop down list boxes using jQuery?

Tags: 2007, jquery

I have two drop down boxes in designer. In the first drop down I have 3 options, in the second drop down I have 20 items.

When I click option 1 in the first drop down, I need the first 6 items populated in the second drop down and the remaining should be removed.

When I select the second option, I need the next 6 items to be populated.

In the same way, the last option as well.

Could anybody give me a start on the logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Marc Anderson's [SPServices jQuery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

There is a function that will do just what you need: [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) (sorry can't link to the exact documentation but you'll find it on this page).

Comment: Have used SPCascade Dropdowns extensively. Great tool.

Comment: AWESOME tool and use it all the time